# HELP! Instruments won't start

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, instruments

Instruments is failing to start on my iPad and iPhone.  Both are correctly provisioned and I can debug code on them from xcode with no problems, but Instruments fails to start.

All I get is a beep.  I looked in the Mac Console logs and I see several of these:

8/18/10 5:46:27 PM Instruments[1406] -[NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11bfd93e0

I tried reboot the Mac, shutting down the iPad, unplugging the iPad, removing the iPad from Organizer.  I've tried deleting the Instruments .plist file.

I've tried both USB ports and different cables.  No luck in getting Instruments to run.

I can run the app just fine from Xcode on the device, just not Instruments.

I have tried this on two different Macs, and I have the same problem.  I tried connecting Instruments to my iPhone and I get the same problem, so I don't think it's the device.  I really don't want to go buy a new iPad just to find out that it doesn't work.

I am able to run Instruments on the simulator, but not the device.  Xcode can build and run the app fine, so there isn't anything fundamentally wrong with the app.

The Instruments drop down that reads "Choose Target" shows my iPad, but not the app like the simulator does.  I tried attaching Instruments to an running version of the app, and the attach menu shows the app, but it's grayed out.

I upgrade to the last Xcode and made sure my iPad was running the lastest and the problem persists.  I am running Xcode 3.2.3 (1688) and Instruments 2.7 (2529).

If I start Instruments directly (not from Xcode), I get a error dialog what says "Device Connection Failed" along with the unknown selector message and I see yellow banners in Instruments that read: "Target failed to run".

Here is the console log from my iPad when Instruments fails to connect:

```
Thu Aug 19 16:16:27 iPad lockdownd[17] <Error>: (0x481000) set_response_error: handle_start_session SessionActive
Thu Aug 19 16:16:28 iPad /usr/libexec/notification_proxy[149] <Error>: Could not receive size of message
Thu Aug 19 16:16:28 iPad /usr/libexec/notification_proxy[149] <Error>: Could not receive message
Thu Aug 19 16:16:48 iPad lockdownd[17] <Error>: (0x481000) handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #6 from Instruments. Killing connection
Thu Aug 19 16:16:48 iPad com.apple.mobile.lockdown[17] <Notice>: receive secure message timeout!
```

Everything worked fine one night and then the next day it starts failing.  I've done nothing to the machine or device between working and not working.

I'm getting very desperate here.  I've posted on the Apple Dev forums, but haven't gotten any responses.

Can anyone help me?  Any advice?

Comment: You may want to revisit your previous questions and accept answers to them that have helped you (by clicking the green tick beneath the appropriate answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by doing a full factory reset of the iPad and the iPhone.  Something got borked on the devices.

If this happens to you, now you know. :-)

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work unfortunately. I still get the error sound when trying to launch Profile. I'm using Xcode 4

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue! I could only use Instruments on my iPhone but not on iPad or iPad2! 
Whenever I started instruments with Xcode 4 it would just beep and the record button would be disabled..

I solved this issue by in XCode going to >Targets>Edit Scheme>Profile "yourAppName" and changing the Build Configuration from Release to Debug.
Then try to profile again Product>Profile

If you get the beep again..
You will see that it says "CHOOSE TARGET" next to the record button open the drop down >Choose Target> "yourAppName" then hit record.

This solved it for me and was finally able to run instruments again!

I know this post is old but i hope it helps someone.

Comment: Tried that but still no luck!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is having problems with "Device Connection Failed," make sure you aren't opening an older version of Instruments (maybe from your dock) that doesn't support the newer devices/iOS 6.  This is a first step in ensuring that Instruments will start for your device.

To solve this, go to **XCode > Open Developer Tools > Instruments** and it will open the newest version of Instruments that's included with your XCode v4.6 install.

Make sure you remove any old docked versions of Instruments and redock the new version.